# Hovering over button has no effect unlike hovering over div-Block

Tags: html, css

I have such a block of elements:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn" >
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <input type="search"  class="search-field" placeholder="Search...">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
  </div>
```

Now I want to display the `dropdown-content` when I am hovering just over button. `.btn:hover .dropdown-content{ dislpay: block; }` has no effect, however hovering over the whole block (`dropdown`) does work. It is also possible to wrap the whole block in an another block and pull the `<input>` to the outer block. But than I'm getting a similar problem with hovering over `<input>`.
My questions are now.

- Why isn't it possible to display the block hovering over the button
- Why hovering over `<input>` has no effect when it is in outer block (this
  is not presented in the code above)
- How can I fix it ?

Comment: There is no `.dropdown-content` within your `.btn`, so why should the selector `.btn:hover .dropdown-content` match anything? Did you mean `.btn:hover ~ .dropdown-content`?

Comment: I've oriented myself by this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_button_split

Comment: and it has no content to display within the button as well

Comment: But I've just tried your suggestion, and it did work. So thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element `.btn .dropdown-content`. `.dropdown-content` is a sibling of `.btn`. So you can use following code. Please check...

```css
.btn:hover + input + .dropdown-content { 
  display: block; 
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn" >
  button
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <input type="search"  class="search-field" placeholder="Search...">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `.btn:hover ~ .dropdown-content {` this CSS also.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzLemapr/)